# Setting the Background of Grouped Inkscape Objects

Tags: inkscape, svg

[In this youtube at the current time](https://youtu.be/5kJAKv-8Yp0?t=159) the designer is able to set the background of 2 grouped objects.  I've tried following the exact same sequence, but when I click on a palette color, the color is applied to the group as a whole.  Is there some trick (Key stroke?) that allows us to only set the color of the background (The square in this case)?

Comment: Can you add the reference of the video or a screenshot, please? The question seems somehow incomplete.

Comment: Ooops - Must have gotten to excited when finding the answer.  It's there now.

Answer (score 1):

Holding down the control (ctrl) key did it.

Comment: CTRL is used to make a selection of an object inside a group while using the Select and Transform Tool (F1). You can also use the Edit Paths by Nodes Tool (F2) to make a selection of a shape inside a group, and then you won't need to hold down CTRL at all.